# How can I split the Dancer error log by day?

Tags: perl, logging, dancer

I am trying to use dancer and starman for my website. And i am succeed in setting the error log into file. Of course i can run a script to move the error log everyday. But I just want to know whether exits method or cpan module to solve the problem.
Thanks~

Answer (score 8):

Do not reinvent the wheel, you will repeat errors of the past that are already fixed.

Use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). It is a unix tool for specifically this kind of task.

To rotate your logs you would usually create a logrotate config for your task in `/etc/logrotate.d/`.

For example to daily rotate and keep your logs for 14 days:

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/dancer-error-log

/path/to/my/dancer-error.log {
    daily
    rotate 14
    create 0660 mydanceruser mydancergroup
}
```